# How to show notification in status bar?

Tags: android, android-notification-bar

So i have created this notification in my activity

```
Notification n = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
    .setContentTitle("New mail from " + sender)
    .setContentText(subject)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification)
    .build();
```

How can i now show it in status/notification bar along with the sound?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is some good [documentation at android developer site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)
and have a look at the [NotificationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html) doc's

Here you go, some code...:

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
// mId allows you to update the notification later on.
mNotificationManager.notify(mId, n);
```

Note that it is also a goo idea to add your intend to the notification...

```
mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
```

To add sound you can use the `Notification.Builder.setSound()` method.

Comment: Is it necessary to add the intent? I mean will it start withouth it when i start the activity?

Comment: and it what's exatcly mId, i mean which value should i assign to it because it shows error this way?

Comment: I never did try without it, but i don't think it will start the activity if you don't add it.

Comment: you can assign any int, you can use this int to update the notification later on

Comment: i have another problem, this seems to be compatitible with 11 and above, and i need it to work on 2.2. Is there another way to notify the user along with the sound

Comment: @Vladimir: Use `NotificationCompat.Builder` from the Android Support package, in place of `Notification.Builder`.

Answer (score 2):

> How can i now show it in status/notification bar along with the sound?

Use the [`Notification.Builder.setSound()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setSound%28android.net.Uri%29) method.

You can get the default ringtone like this:

```
Uri uri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
```

and then set it as notification sound:

```
Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext()).setSound(uri);
```

and then after you've built your notification you launch it with:

```
myNotificationManager.notify(myNotificationId, n);
```